# Finding top n correlated features(based on Pearson cofficient) with class attribute Python scikit learn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm pretty new to Python and Machine Learning.

I have a dataset with several features. I want to find top 'n' correlated attributes/features with class attribute using Pearson coefficient. How can I do that.

Below is my dataset structure:
class_attr col1 col2 col3 ... coln

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the details that you have posted in your question, I am assuming this to be a classification problem and not a regression one. In that case, it is not feasible to use Pearson Coefficient as a metric for correlation.

You can [Recursive Feature Elimination with Cross Validation (RFECV)](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html#sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV) to get the optimal number of features and their corresponding feature importance. Check out this code based on the [example on this link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_selection/plot_rfe_with_cross_validation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-feature-selection-plot-rfe-with-cross-validation-py).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
svc = SVC(kernel="linear")
rfecv = RFECV(estimator=svc, step=1, cv=StratifiedKFold(labels, 50),
      scoring='precision')
rfecv.fit(features, labels)
print("Optimal number of features : %d" % rfecv.n_features_)
print rfecv.support_
features=features[:,rfecv.support_]
# Plot number of features VS. cross-validation scores
plt.figure()
plt.xlabel("Number of features selected")
plt.ylabel("Cross validation score (nb of correct classifications)")
plt.plot(range(1, len(rfecv.grid_scores_) + 1), rfecv.grid_scores_)
plt.show()
```

**Sample Output** :[image]

Alternatively, you can use the [selectKbest Method](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest) to specify your custom scoring function and get the scores for each of the features using the `.scores_` attribute.

[This is a good blog post](https://machinelearningmastery.com/feature-selection-machine-learning-python/) on Feature Selection in Scikit-learn.

[Here is another blog post](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/12/introduction-to-feature-selection-methods-with-an-example-or-how-to-select-the-right-variables/) with multiple methods along with their examples.

Also, you can take a look at the [official documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html) for more such APIs.